# Can the Droid Eris be charged on a PowerPlate Wireless Induction Charging Base?

Tags: battery, charging, droid-eris

Can the [Droid Eris](http://www.htc.com/us/products/droid-eris-verizon/#overview) be charged on a [PowerPlate Wireless Induction Charging Base](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003U563X0)?

Comment: Nevermind the question was more appropriate listed here: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3543/can-the-droid-eris-be-charged-on-a-powerplate-wireless-induction-charging-base

Comment: That's the URL for this question.

Answer (score 6):

[eldarerathis](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/981/eldarerathis) is right.  The PowerPlate is a two part system.  1. The Base and 2. The Receiver.  The receiver clips onto the phone and is specific to the phone.  It looks like the powerplate system replaces the battery cover on the blackberry and is a snap-on cover for the iphone.

**Duracell makes an [inductive charger](http://www.duracell.com/en-US/product/mygrid-kits.jspx) that is compatible with the Eris.**  [PowerMat](http://www.powermat.com/us/receivers.html) doesn't have an Eris receiver but they have some universals.  Or you could [hack your own solution](http://hackaday.com/2010/08/01/update-custom-cellphone-induction-charging/).

Comment: I would definitely consider the PowerMat.  IMHO, they have a better known product.  The prices for some of their products are also comparable to the PowerPlate.  I'm sure the myGrid is also a good product.

Comment: So it looks like you can use the power cube to charge it with the PowerMat, but at that point you mightas well just plug it in (http://twitter.com/#!/Powermat/status/14807354381959168)

Comment: Yeah, the power cube is a little silly, but I guess if you had several powermat compatible devices and one stray, it'd be a decent alternative.  You could still go with the Duracell MyGrid, although I'm not a big fan of the little nub that would end up poking out.

Answer (score 5):

The product description on [Brookstone's site](http://www.brookstone.com/ipod-accessory-products_powerplate-wireless-induction-charging-base.html?bkiid=productDetail|CXConsiderationProductsFDT|9206785) (and the Amazon one mentions this, too) seems to indicate that you can't. They specifically list that there are receivers for iPhone 3G/3GS and Blackberry Curve 8900. You can't charge something without the receiver/case, so if they don't make one for the Eris (which it appears they do not) then it won't work.

That being said, you could always stop by or call your local Brookstone and ask, I suppose.